# Research Proposal help

Tags: soft-question, advice

Soft question, so I hope this is still in the right place. I have applied for a PhD position at the university I have just finished my undergrad degree at. I have to write a research proposal in the area of pattern analysis. It is suggested that I use research papers to critique existing research and outline my approach and why my approach might be novel.

I am completely new to this being my first application, and I'm also not very familiar with the area of pattern analysis (although I'm confident I can certainly be on top of this before the position starts in September). Any guidance would be greatly appreciated; I am not too sure where I am looking for research papers, or if there is a standard length/structure/template this must follow. I have attached the information sheet with which I am to base the proposal on. Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Any reason for the downvotes? I thought a lot of the regular users would be experienced in this. Happy to move it elsewhere if this is the wrong place.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted, but maybe the academia.SE would be a better place to get answers... I just say: maybe

Comment: @AnaGalois Thanks for the suggestion. I will do if there's an issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scholar.google.com is where you can search for it online. But I want very much to recommend you to talk to your university library so that you know what journals you have access to, and how to access them.